# Is there any way to enable n+k patterns in Frege?

Tags: frege

In Haskell I have to start `ghci` with `-XNPlusKPatterns` or add `{-# LANGUAGE NPlusKPatterns #-}` in source file to make this work:

```
pred :: Int -> Int
pred 0 = 0
pred (n + 1) = n
```

Is `n+k` pattern deliberately passed  over in Frege or there exists a way to enable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `(n+k)` patterns were already obsolete when frege was written, so they're not included.